# Why is this ring-buffer jumping?

Tags: audio, analog-to-digital, digital-to-analog

**Central problem (Abstract):**

A simple implementation of a two-buffer ring-buffer jumps after filling up completely. What am I missing?

**About:**

- ADC to DAC feedthrough
- STM32L476RG NUCLEO as MCU
- Intended application: DSP for audio
- HAL: STM32 Cube HAL
- Buffersize: 2048 samples
- Academic project by electronics students, first steps with DSP on MCUs

**Mode of operation:**

[image: Diagram]

**Problem illustrated:**

*I apologize for the pictures. I currently do not have access to screenshots from the ocilloscope itself.*

[image: Waveform]

The yellow waveform is a 20kHz sinewave with 1.65V offset. Ignore the green channel for now. As is visible, the waveform jumps every buffer.

[image: Waveform_close]

A closeup of the buffer reveals that data is wrongly fed to the DAC. The waveform seems to break for a moment and use data from previous moments. I have yet to find the reason for this.

> The green signal is a GPIO which is toggled by software for debugging purposes. See the code below for more information.

**Code:**

```
// global vars
uint16_t adc_buf[FULL_BUF_LEN];
uint16_t dac_buf[FULL_BUF_LEN];
uint16_t i;

static volatile uint16_t* pIn = &adc_buf[0];
static volatile uint16_t* pOut = &dac_buf[HALF_BUF_LEN];

uint8_t hlfcplt = 0;
uint8_t cplt = 0;


// functions
int mymain(void){

    HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*)adc_buf, FULL_BUF_LEN);
    HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac1, DAC1_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t*)dac_buf, FULL_BUF_LEN, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim6);

    while(1){
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        dsp();
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
}

void dsp(void){

    if(hlfcplt){
        for(i = 0; i < HALF_BUF_LEN; i++){
            pOut[i] = pIn[i];
        }
        hlfcplt = 0;
    }
    if(cplt){
        for(i = 0; i < HALF_BUF_LEN; i++){
            pOut[i] = pIn[i];
        }
        cplt = 0;
    }
}

// callbacks
void HAL_ADC_ConvHalfCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc){

    pIn = &adc_buf[0];
    pOut = &dac_buf[HALF_BUF_LEN];
    hlfcplt = 1;

}

void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc){
    pIn = &adc_buf[HALF_BUF_LEN];
    pOut = &dac_buf[0];
    cplt = 1;
}
```

This follows standard ring-buffer guides but nobody adresses this error. Which part of the code causes this behavior?

Comment: where are `FULL_BUF_LEN` and `HALF_BUF_LEN` defined?  I just think there are simpler ways of doing ping-pong buffers.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson they are defined in a header file, but their size is mentioned above: FULL_BUF_LEN is 2048

Comment: Wondering when the callbacks get called... and why copy the same thing for `cplt = 1` and `hlfcplt = 1` in `dsp()`?

Comment: @PeterK. called after the ADC has completed or half completed the conversion of a whole buffer, meaning 1024 or 2048 samples

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson what would be more efficient? As far as i can tell this is the only way I can achieve a ping pong buffer with DMA

Comment: I'm wondering if setting / resetting the GPIO in the callbacks might be more instructive.  I keep coming back to the DMA happening while the data is being transferred. It shouldn't happen, but seeing when the buffers swap might help.

Comment: SOLUTION: I don't want to answer my question because I have no idea WHY this fixes it: bind both DAC and ADC to **different** timers and trigger them via interrupts. This produces the same error UNLESS you add a small `HAL_delay()` between the starting of the timers

Answer (score -1):

perhaps?

```
while(1){
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    dsp();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    dsp();
}
```

what does `GPIO_PIN_9` connect to?

Comment: No, this does not work. Essentially, I just call dsp() twice in a single loop iteration but change the GPIO at double that speed. The GPIO is just for debugging purposes and is seen as the green signal on the oscilloscope